# Функция отправки формы для нескольких Div contenteditable

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

есть функция отправки формы для Div contenteditable, которая работает только для одной формы, как переписать скрипт, чтобы отправка шла для каждой формы, которые будут на странице? Вот рабочий пример:

```
<?
$bb_code = '
<div class="bb_code">
    <button onclick="document.execCommand(\'bold\', false, null); return false"><b>Жирный текст</b></button>
</div>';


 echo '
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <!-- Div contenteditable -->
            <div onclick="displayHtml();">
                <div class="div_contable-js div_contable" onkeyup="JavaScript:displayHtml();" data-placeholder="Текст сообщения" contenteditable="true"></div>
                <textarea class="source_textarea-js _active" name="text" maxlength="790" onkeypress="return displayHtml()" required></textarea>
                '.$bb_code.'
            </div>
        <!-- / -->
        <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Отправить" />
    </form>
    
    
    <form method="POST" action="">
        <!-- Div contenteditable -->
            <div onclick="displayHtml();">
                <div class="div_contable-js div_contable" onkeyup="JavaScript:displayHtml();" data-placeholder="Текст сообщения" contenteditable="true"></div>
                <textarea class="source_textarea-js" name="text" maxlength="790" onkeypress="return displayHtml()" required></textarea>
                '.$bb_code.'
            </div>
        <!-- / -->
        <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Отправить" />
    </form>
    ';
    
?>

<style>
.div_contable {width: 400px; min-height: 80px; padding: 5px; border-radius: 6px; border: 1px solid #CBCFD2;}
textarea {display: none}
button {margin: 1em}
</style>

<script>
/*Отправка формы*/
function displayHtml() {
    HTMLCode = document.querySelector('.div_contable-js').innerHTML;
    document.querySelector('.source_textarea-js').textContent = HTMLCode;
    return HTMLCode;
}
</script>
```